# how to replace timestamp with 1 and 0?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to replace the enrolment time log with 1  and the null cells with 0 on a large dataset, below is a sample:

```
data = [['tom', '10', "2014-02-05 21:24:44 UTC"], ['nick', '',''], ['juli', 14, '2014-02-15 21:55:43 UTC']]

BD = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Enrolled_at'])
```

I've tried the following code but they are for replacing a certain value and in my dateset, the timestamps are not unique.

1

```
BD['enrolled_at'].replace('', "1", inplace=True)
BD.head()
```

2

```
BD.loc[(BD['enrolled_at'] > 1990)] = 1
```

3

```
BD['enrolled_at'].replace("$20$", "1", regex=True, inplace=True)
BD
```

.

eThe current situation

[image: The current situation]

.

Expected result

[image: Expected result]

Comment: You can try using np.where with 0 as default

Answer (score 3):

```
BD['Enrolled_at'] = pd.to_datetime(BD['Enrolled_at'])

BD['Enrolled_at'] = np.where(BD['Enrolled_at'] > '1990-01-01', 1, 0)
```

You can set the 1990 date to the lowest value of dates in your data

Answer (score 1):

```
if BD['Enrolled_at'] == '':
    BD['Enrolled_at] = 0
else:
    BD['Enrolled_at'] = 1
```